# Is there a function which performs stepwise forward or backward selection when doing a logistic regression?

Tags: python, regression

I want to perform a logistic regression in python on a dataset of 100 variables. I want to select a subset of these variables. I there a function in python which could do a stepwise forward/backward selection when doing a logistic regression?